# Fontawesome Wordpress Icon CSS rule

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to use  WordPress fontawesome Icon but I can't find the CSS rule anywhere. 
found the rule below but it shows up broken. any idea on how this can be achieved.

I know how to use font awesome but I'm trying to insert the WordPress icon via CSS. Every other iconis showing except for that of Wordpress.

```
 .side-box ul li:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content:"\f205";
    width: auto;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
    color: #69B5D5;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your actual question is. I think this will help you: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Comment: Nico I know how to use font awesome but I'm trying to insert the WordPress icon via CSS.

Comment: **How** are you trying to insert the icon though? What is the rest of your CSS? Just putting `content` somewhere won't be enough to achieve anything, but I can't really help without knowing more about what you are doing.

Comment: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ and search the page for "wordpress". Also see [the disclaimer here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#brand) about Adblock Plus.

Comment: Blazemonger I'd use "<i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>" directory in the HTML if that is what I want but the sidebar is dynamic so I must insert it via CSS.

Comment: [`content: "\f19a";`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/wordpress/)

Comment: Do you have the latest FontAwesome font (version 4.1)? The wordpress icon just came out in the last update.

Comment: Blazemonger that did it. Thanks.